# DELETE with curl CouchDB

Tags: curl, couchdb

Consider the following PUT requests that build a CouchDB Database and add a document

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/mydb
```

Response: {"ok":true}

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/mydb/mydoc -d '{"name":"John", "email":"john@example.com"}'
```

Response: {"ok":true,"id":"mydoc","rev":"1-8c497db1c5b38cb65981a2c83b349d83"}

Ok, we've got a document.  Now I want to delete this document.  I try:

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:5984/mydb/mydoc -d '{"_rev":"1-8c497db1c5b38cb65981a2c83b349d83}'
```

Response: {"error":"conflict","reason":"Document update conflict."}

Hmm.  I don't see why that doesn't work, so I try this:

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:5984/mydb/mydoc?rev=1-8c497db1c5b38cb65981a2c83b349d83
```

Response: {"ok":true,"id":"mydoc","rev":"2-e8b8b0632384aae62338c57e1826ea81"}

That works...but why?  What's wrong with the first?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DELETE` requests shares `GET` semantics and message body is [ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request), so you need to use query parameters to pass revision token with request.

Comment: I suppose that ultimately makes sense.  Thanks for the info!